# Error Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type '() => Map<String, dynamic>?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

today I got this error:  `Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type '() => Map<String, dynamic>?' The relevant error-causing widget was: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>> StreamBuilder:file:[Filepath]`
which is this widget:

```
              return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(

                stream: database.getTodos(),

                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  else {
                    // resolve stream... Stream<DocumentSnapshot> -> DocumentSnapshot -> Map<String, bool>
                    Map<String, dynamic> items = snapshot.data?.data as Map<String, dynamic>;

                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: items.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          String key = items.keys.elementAt(i);
                          return ToDoItem(
                            key,
                            items[key],
                                () => deleteItem(key),
                                () => toggleDone(key, items[key]),
                          );
                        });
                  }
                },
              );
```

the error is causing from the Firestore Database, but I don´t know how to fix it.
If you need something more to slove it, please comment and I will give you the code for it.
I tried to slove it with adding some `?`around or change the type `Map` oh and I also changed

```
  Stream getTodos() {
    return userTodos.document(userID).snapshots();
  }
```

in the database class to

```
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getTodos() {
    return userTodos.doc(userID).snapshots();
  }
```

but it doesn´t fix this error but another error.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you wrote `snapshot.data?.data` but the second data is a function that returns a map, not a map itself, so you need to call it: `snapshot.data?.data()`